# Merging overlapping transparent shapes in directx

Tags: geometry, directx, shader, sharpdx

This is the problem I am facing simplified:
Using directx I need to draw two(or more) exactly (in the same 2d plane) overlapping triangles. The triangles are semi transparent but the effect I want to release is that they clip to transparency of a single triangle. The picture below might depict the problem better.

[image: Current and wanted result]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, as you tagged your question with the shader tag: `max(tri1Color, tri2Color);`

Comment: @LJᛃ thx for the suggestion. The number of triangles can be more than two and if they are both drawn with max transparency the result will be the same so I am afraid this won't work

Comment: Was solved by enabling the depth stencil, I had to disable it prior to writing the invisible objects causing this behavior. Forgot to enable it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the depth stencil prevents this problem

Comment: Just a heads up, in games, Z test is usually enabled on Alpha, but not Z Write (so the surface wont overwrite opaque forground items).  The transparent items are usually sorted from back to front.  Therefore accumulation of colour/opaqueness.  If you have 2 different transparent surfaces at the same location on screen with the same Z depth, you will end up with Z fighting depending on the rejection test you set.   Usually, you set a blend state.  Retest your solution with different coloured triangles, you may get z fighting.  Good luck.

Comment: can you share some code snippet how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get overlapping transparent triangles to not "accumulate".  You need to create a blendstate and set it on output merge.

> ```
>     blendStateDescription.AlphaToCoverageEnable = false;
> ```

```
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].IsBlendEnabled = true;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SourceBlend = D3D11.BlendOption.SourceAlpha;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestinationBlend = D3D11.BlendOption.One; //
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOperation = D3D11.BlendOperation.Maximum;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SourceAlphaBlend = D3D11.BlendOption.SourceAlpha; //Zero
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestinationAlphaBlend = D3D11.BlendOption.DestinationAlpha;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].AlphaBlendOperation = D3D11.BlendOperation.Maximum;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11.ColorWriteMaskFlags.All;
```

Hope this helps.  Code is in C# but it works the same in C++ etc.  Basically, takes the alpha of both source and destination, compares and takes the max.  Which will always be the same (as long as you use the same alpha on both triangles) otherwise it will render the one with the most alpha.

edit: I've added a sample of what the blending does in my project.  The roads here overlap.  [Overlap Sample](http://www.insanesoftware.com.au/wip6.jpg)

My pixel shader is as:

I pass the UV co-ords in a float4.

xy = uv coords.
w is the alpha value.

Pixel shader code

```
float4 pixelColourBlend;
pixelColourBlend = primaryTexture.Sample(textureSamplerStandard, input.uv.xy,    0);
pixelColourBlend.w = input.uv.w;
clip(pixelColourBlend.w - 0.05f);
return pixelColourBlend;
```

Ignore my responses, couldn't edit them...grrrr.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I guess this is the way to go but I can't get it to work. Tried a lot of different settings on the blendstate but it does not do what I want. The SourceAlphaBlend, DestinationAlphaBlend and AlphaBlendOperation don't even seem to do anything. Do I maybe need to add something to the pixel shader?

Comment: `code`    float4 pixelColourBlend;
 
    pixelColourBlend = primaryTexture.Sample(textureSamplerStandard, input.uv.xy, 0);

    pixelColourBlend.w = input.uv.w;
    clip(pixelColourBlend.w - 0.05f);


    return pixelColourBlend;

Comment: '    float4 pixelColourBlend;
 
    pixelColourBlend = primaryTexture.Sample(textureSamplerStandard, input.uv.xy, 0);

    pixelColourBlend.w = input.uv.w;
    clip(pixelColourBlend.w - 0.05f);


    return pixelColourBlend;'

Comment: Thanks for all the help @ErnieDingo. I looked into your suggestions for quite some time until I figured out that the depth stencil was disabled, when enabled the overlap problems do not occur.

Comment: Works nicely for colors, but if i have a transparent BLACK object, it becomes transparent. It doesn't like black.